# Converting sqlite database to postgres yields DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I'm uploading the database for my Django app to Heroku using using `db:push` which converts my database from sqlite to postgres.

However, during the process I get the error:

`Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  integer out of range`

When I try to create a clean database on Heroku's server using `python manage.py syncdb`, I get a similar message:

```
Installing index for django_openid.UserOpenidAssociation model
Installing json fixture 'initial_data' from '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/oembed/fixtures'.
Installing json fixture 'initial_data' from '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/pinax/apps/photos/fixtures'.
Installing json fixture 'initial_data' from '/app/store/fixtures'.
Problem installing fixture '/app/store/fixtures/initial_data.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 169, in handle
obj.save(using=using)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in save_base
rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 491, in _update
return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 861, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)
```

It looks to me that the problem lies in the initial data, but not entirely sure. I found a post here that said it could be a problem with encoding of a field but even if I were to look into that not exactly sure how to read the error message to find out what exactly is causing the problem and also to pinpoint which table/column might be causing the problem.

Comment: do you have the DDL for your sqlite database? how about the postgresql database? could you post that, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)` means that you're trying to store a string longer than 50 characters in into a VARCHAR(50) type. You can weed down potential candidates by looking through your models for `CharField`s with `max_length=50`, or `SlugField`s (which default to `max_length=50`). Then, look through your `initial_data.json` fixtures and see if you notice any obviously long strings being stored for any of those fields.

Comment: Thanks for that advice... I pinpointed the problem -- but it didn't solve the original `Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  integer out of range` during the push. I'm guessing it's unrelated so I'll post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChrisPratt said, I had the same problem, but was not able to figure out the problem. I had only one app in my project, I deleted *py files in migration folder of the app ( except **init**.py file) and  cleared all tables in my sqlite3 db ( I didn't have any important data at that time) and then ran migrate command. It worked!.